# show values of parent row in ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, nested

I'm a bit stuck here

i have an array of 'parcel' objects, but i want to display a value of the parent object of this parcel how can i achieve this?

i have created this fiddle:
i would like to show also the buyer

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.filter('createarray', function () {
return function (value, propertyName) {
    var arrayList = [];
    angular.forEach(value, function (val) {
        angular.forEach(val[propertyName], function (v) {
            arrayList.push(v)
        });
    });
    console.log(arrayList)
    return arrayList;
}
});
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {


$scope.ordersList = {
    "orders": [{
        "ordernum": "PRAAA000000177800601",
            "buyer": "Donna Heywood",
            "parcels": [{
            "upid": "UPID567890123456",
                "tpid": "TPID789456789485"
        }, {
            "upid": "UPID586905486090",
                "tpid": "TPID343454645455"
        }]
    }, {
        "ordernum": "ORAAA000000367567345",
            "buyer": "Melanie Daniels",
            "parcels": [{
            "upid": "UPID456547347776",
                "tpid": "TPID645896579688"
        }, {
            "upid": "UPID768577673366",
                "tpid": "TPID784574333345"
        }]
    }]
}
});


<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="o in ordersList.orders | createarray: 'parcels'">
        <li>upid= {{o.upid}}</li>
        <li>tpid= {{o.tpid}}</li>
        <li>buyer= {{o.buyer}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/exon02/w00eo4bz/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your filter `createarray` you loop through `parcels` array which doesn't contain any information about `buyer`. So, you should update your filter to following:

```
myApp.filter('createarray', function () {
    return function (value, propertyName) {
        var arrayList = [];
        angular.forEach(value, function (val) {
            angular.forEach(val[propertyName], function (v) {
                v.buyer = val.buyer; //Here you should save information about buyer from your parent object, that has this property.
                arrayList.push(v)
            });
        });
        console.log(arrayList)
        return arrayList;
    }
});
```

Comment: Optionally you can also create a new object if you don't wanna modify you original objects with `angular.copy`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your fiddle and it now shows the buyer. You don't have to do exactly as I did, but this just serves to display what is missing from your fiddle.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    {{ctrl.someVar}}
    <ul ng-repeat="x in ctrl.ordersList">

        <li>buyer= {{x.buyer}}</li>
        <ul ng-repeat="p in x.parcels">
            <li>{{p.upid}}</li>
            <li>{{p.tpid}}</li>
        </ul>

    </ul>
</div>
```

And I also changed the model:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    this.someVar = 3;
    this.ordersList = 
         [{
            "ordernum": "PRAAA000000177800601",
                "buyer": "Donna Heywood",
                "parcels": 
             [{
                    "upid": "UPID567890123456",
                    "tpid": "TPID789456789485"
              }, 
              {
                    "upid": "UPID586905486090",
                    "tpid": "TPID343454645455"
             }]
          }, 
          {
            "ordernum": "ORAAA000000367567345",
                "buyer": "Melanie Daniels",
                "parcels": 
                [{
                    "upid": "UPID456547347776",
                    "tpid": "TPID645896579688"
                }, 
                {
                    "upid": "UPID768577673366",
                    "tpid": "TPID784574333345"
                }]
        }]

});
```

It does show the buyer and parcel info.